# Validating fields

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, c#-4.0

I have on my windows form something like this

```
   field1                field 2                        mandatory             showfield

   textbox1               textbox2                      checkbox1          checkbox 2

   textbox3              textbox4                       checkbox3          checkbox4
```

.... 5 fields just like this in total

what i want is to iterate through the textboxes first if they are filled i want to check the checkboxes if they are checked or not

i have the data in the following

```
string[] textdata = { textBox1.Text, textBox2.Text, textBox3.Text, textBox4.Text, textBox5.Text, textBox6.Text, textBox7.Text, textBox8.Text, textBox9.Text, textBox10.Text, textBox11.Text };
bool[] chk = { checkBox1.Checked, checkBox2.Checked, checkBox3.Checked, checkBox4.Checked, checkBox5.Checked, checkBox6.Checked, checkBox7.Checked, checkBox8.Checked, checkBox9.Checked, checkBox10.Checked, checkBox11.Checked, checkBox12.Checked };
```

this is what i tried

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Comment: Please, get more details of your question, so we can help you.

Comment: Your question is very vague. It is unclear what you are trying to accomplish exactly. Please spell it out completely.

Answer (score 1):

You can get all the text boxes in a list and then iterate in each box to check data..

```
List<TextBox> textBoxes = formObject.Controls.OfType<TextBox>();

   foreach(TextBox txtBox in textBoxes)
   {
       if(txtBox.Text == "")
         //Do some work
   }
```

Similarly you can perform operations for other controls

Comment: Use the extension method `OfType<T>` instead of the `Where(type check)` http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb360913.aspx `returns only those elements in source that can be cast to type TResult`

Comment: but i want to check the corresponding ones like textbox1, textbox2, checkbox1, checkbox2

Comment: do it manually.. one by one

Comment: @JayantVarshney Well the code is a bit clearer now, but does it solve the question? Who knows.

Comment: haha.. This man wants **corresponding ones like textbox1, textbox2, checkbox1, checkbox2**... i don't know how can we do this..

Comment: @user1862352: if you have certain critera's then you can make some LINQ queries according to your custom requirement or check them one by one

Comment: is it possible to use for loop

Comment: @user1862352 I typed something up that might work. Really though your question is * extremely* unclear.

Answer (score 1):

```
foreach (Textbox g in this.Controls.OfType<Textbox>())
{
if(g.text == "")
{
this.Controls[checkbox[gettextbox name and parse it to getnumber]].checked = true;    }  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since there is no real question/problem i'm guessing what the problem could be.

> what i want is to iterate through the textboxes first if they are
>   filled i want to check the checkboxes if they are checked or not
>
> i have the data in the following

```
string[] textdata = { textBox1.Text, textBox2.Text, textBox3.Text, textBox4.Text, textBox5.Text, textBox6.Text, textBox7.Text, textBox8.Text, textBox9.Text, textBox10.Text, textBox11.Text };
bool[] chk = { checkBox1.Checked, checkBox2.Checked, checkBox3.Checked, checkBox4.Checked, checkBox5.Checked, checkBox6.Checked, checkBox7.Checked, checkBox8.Checked, checkBox9.Checked, checkBox10.Checked, checkBox11.Checked, checkBox12.Checked };
```

So you could use [`Enumerable.All`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb548541.aspx) to check if all TextBoxes are filled:

```
bool allTextEntered = textdata.All(s => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(s));
```

Then you can show a `MessageBox` if something is missing, otherwise you can check if all `CheckBoxes` are checked:

```
bool allCheckBoxChecked = chk.All(chk => chk);
```

Answer (score 0):

Something simple that should work would be to setup the textbox/checkbox relationship in the textbox's `Tag` property, IE:

```
this.textbox1.Tag = this.checkbox1
//continue per textbox in this pattern
```

Then just query the collection for items matching the predicate of "Does the textbox have a value? Is yes, is the checkbox checked?"

The final answer is if the previous query returned any items.

```
var isValid = this.Controls.OfType<Textbox>()
                  .Where(textbox => 
                          !string.IsNullOfWhitespace(textbox.Text) && 
                          (textbox.Tag as Checkbox).Checked)).Any();
```

This is assuming of course that the textbox(n)/checkbox(n) validation is correct, the question is very unclear.